# Could not find the correct Provider<UserHomeBloc> above this UserHomeScreen Widget

Tags: flutter, bloc, provider

I'm trying to connect a Bloc using the Provider package in my Flutter app, and I'm facing an issue in the bloc configuration. The error message I'm getting is:

```
Could not find the correct Provider<UserHomeBloc> above this UserHomeScreen Widget
```

`Bloc Config`

```
part of './bloc/user_home_bloc.dart';

@RoutePage()
class UserHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget implements AutoRouteWrapper {
  const UserHomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<UserHomeScreen> createState() => _UserHomeScreenState();

  @override
  Widget wrappedRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      create: (ctx) => UserHomeBloc(),
      child: this,
    );
  }
}

class _UserHomeScreenState extends State<UserHomeScreen> {
  late ProgressDialog progressDialog;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context: context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 27.w,
                  height: 27.h,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100).w,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      width: 1.w,
                    ),
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('images/girl1 1.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          title: const Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          // Add some space between the leading and title
          titleSpacing: 15.0,
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 380,
              height: 150,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0).r,
                  child: BlocListener<UserHomeBloc, UserHomeState>(
                    listener: _getDataListner,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          onDoubleTap: () {
                            context.read<UserHomeBloc>().add(_GetDataEvent(
                                category: Category.Football.category()));
                          },
                          child: IconContainer(
                            icons:
                                'https://ik.imagekit.io/wdjnrplts/Icons/Vector-3_GgygmyeHQ.png?updatedAt=1703517376519',
                            name: 'Football',
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 15),
                        IconContainer(
                          icons:
                              'https://ik.imagekit.io/wdjnrplts/Icons/Vector-3_GgygmyeHQ.png?updatedAt=1703517376519',
                          name: 'Cricket',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 280,
                    height: 47,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 240,
                          height: 47,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: 'Search here',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF727272),
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  fontFamily: 'Fira Sans',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  height: 0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 20.w,
                          height: 20.h,
                          child: Image.network(
                              'https://ik.imagekit.io/wdjnrplts/Icons/search-2-line%201_i3OsNA68w7.png?updatedAt=1703526284008'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 45,
                    height: 47,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 11,
                      left: 11,
                      right: 10,
                      bottom: 12,
                    ),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://ik.imagekit.io/wdjnrplts/Icons/filter-2-line%201__mFAXhLrZh.png?updatedAt=1703528066103',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 35.0,
                  maxHeight: 250.h,
                ),
                child: ScrollConfiguration(
                  behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context)
                      .copyWith(scrollbars: false),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemExtent: 220.0,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return HomeDetails(
                        mainImage:
                            'https://i2.wp.com/cricketgraph.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/JES-Turf-Jogeshwari-1.jpg?fit=763%2C405&ssl=1',
                        turf: 'ABC Soccer Club\nKakkanad',
                        adress: 'kakkanad infopark \ncampus',
                        discrption:
                            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Consequat fames pellentesque elementum.',
                        time: 'Mon - sun 4am - 12am',
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getDataListner(BuildContext ctx, UserHomeState state) {
    if (state is _Loading) {
      progressDialog.show(msg: "Featching Data");
    } else {
      if (state is _Success) {
        progressDialog.close();
      } else if (state is _Failed) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(state.error)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Bloc Code`

```
class UserHomeBloc extends Bloc<UserHomeEvent, UserHomeState> {
  UserHomeBloc() : super(const _Initial()) {
    on<_GetDataEvent>((event, emit) async {
      final UserHomeRepo userHomeRepo = UserHomeRepo();
      try {
        final response = await userHomeRepo.userHomeRes(event.category);
        if (response != null && response.error == null) {
          emit(_Success(response: response));
        } else {
          emit(_Failed(error: response?.error ?? "unknown error"));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        emit(_Failed(error: e.toString()));
      }
    });
  }

 
}
```

In my autoroute configuration, I am seamlessly integrating state management with the bloc package by connecting a Bloc using the provider package